# Passing callable in lambda capture

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, sicp, callable-object

While reading [SICP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262510871)'s section about "Formulating Abstractions with Higher-OrderFunctions" I was curious to implement a simple, root solving procedure using Newtons' Method in C++.

However my implementation is faulty but I cannot figure out why. The code compiles but I got a runtime crash due to stack overflow because the loop recursion inside fixedPoint function cannot reach MAX_IT. I run it in Debug mode so tail recursion does not apply.

The problem is that the function g inside fixedPoint is never evaluated correctly (I always get inf. result). I think that I miss something about callable passing and lambda captures (I try to pass std::function in lambda). Below I have the sample code which runs a square root problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>

static constexpr double DELTA = 0.0000001;
static constexpr int MAX_IT = 50000;
using my_function = std::function<double(double)>;

double derivative(const my_function& f, const double x) {
    return (f(x + DELTA) - f(x)) / DELTA;
}

bool isConverge(const double p1, const double p2) {
    return std::abs(p1 - p2) < DELTA;
}

double fixedPoint(const my_function& g, double x = 1) {

    int itCnt = 0;
    std::function<double(double, double)> loop;
    loop = [&g, &itCnt, &loop](double x0, double x1) -> double {
        if (isConverge(x0, x1) || (++itCnt > MAX_IT)) return x1;
        return loop(x1, g(x1));
    };

    return loop(x, g(x));
}

my_function newtonsMethod(const my_function& f) {
    return [&f](double x) -> double {return x - f(x) / derivative(f, x); };
}

double findRoot(const my_function& f) {
    return fixedPoint(newtonsMethod(f));
}

double sqRoot(double x) { 
    return findRoot([x](int y) {return y * y - x; });
}

int main() {
    const double num = 133;
    std::cout << "Square root " << num << ": " << sqRoot(num) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is. Does it compile? Does it give the wrong results?

Comment: @cigien I updated the post accordingly. I hope that I made it clear.

Comment: Yes, that's clearer, thanks.

Comment: @Artyer itCnt seems to work properly. I print out its value and its increasing linearly. I also decreased MAX_IT to 100 and then I got a result without crashing. However the result is inf as the function g is not evaluated correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is `int` truncation from double with

```
return findRoot([x](int y) {return y * y - x; });
```

So when you compute `derivative`, you obtain 0.

Change to

```
return findRoot([x](double y) {return y * y - x; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4a8f61687e57973)

Comment: I forgot this type there from the beginning... It was so simple! Thank you!